# How can I print on the console all the content of a specific class from a website I am crawling in?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I am using `scrapy` in order to extract content from a website. This is part of the websites element structure:

[image]
I want to print on the console all the content that is contained in the `single-main-content` class and therefore I have written the following script:

```
import scrapy

class SkillsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'skills'

    start_urls = [
        'http://data.europa.eu/esco/skill/1a4cc54f-1e53-442b-a6d2-1682dc8ef8f9'
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for items in response.css('single-main-content'):
            text = items.css('single-main-content').extract()
            print(text)
```

Despite that, nothing related to it is printed on my console. Can someone please help me understand what I am doing wrong? I appreciate any help

Comment: `.single-main-content *::text` will select whole text 

`.single-main-content` is used for selecting article element `*` means any child `::text` will select text out of that elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'single-main-content'` is a css class but when you do:
 `response.css('single-main-content')` 
you are searching for a HTML element, you should do: 
 `response.css('.single-main-content')`

And when you do `for items in response.css('.single-main-content'):` you're iterating every element inside that container so you won't find `.single-main-content` there you should try something like `for items in response.css('*::text'):` instead.